# React or node project automation test

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, typescript

I have a project.That is made in React,Node or MongoDB. Actually i want 
create an automation test. Which test (login or register) form will be automatically fill. If anyone have some idea then please give me.

Comment: Try using selenium

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

The fastest you use puppeteer nodejs